# How to remove duplicate objects from arrays based on association records in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have to Arrays one is `users` and another one `assignments` and `users` is multidimensional array like below

```
users = [
  {id: 1, name: 'john'},
  {id: 2, name: 'john'},
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'john', 
    assignments: [
      {id: 1, userId: 3, postId: 2}
    ]
  },  
]

assignments = [
    {id: 1, userId: 3, postId: 2}
]
```

the I tried

```
const usersIDs = new Set(users.map(({ id }) => id))
const combined = [
    ...users,
    ...assignments.filter(({ userId }) => !usersIDs.has(userId))
]
```

I want to remove the object from users where `id` & `users.assignments.postId` match with `assignments` table.

I have tried with several ways that find over Google but not luck.

Whats should I do now? How could I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: You have to show your attempt where you got the closest to the solution. That's how we can know what you're having difficulty with. Otherwise, we're just writing code for you and are not helping you understand where you went wrong. Suggestion: use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Also, please make sure your properties align

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for your suggestions, I have updated the code as you said. My issue still not resolved!

Comment: It's still unclear what your output is supposed to be. It's also unclear how you expected your code to work. Please work on asking a clear question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You should always explain the actual behavior contrasted with the expected behavior. For example, I expected combined to look like `[...]` but it looked like`[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code to acheive your output

```
assignments.forEach(asgn => {
    if (users.some(user => user.id === asgn.postId)) {
        const index = users.findIndex(user => user.id === asgn.postId);
        users.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
console.log(users);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have tried but not working even not showing any error

Comment: I have edited the code, added console log after the code, 
Please check now

Comment: :)  Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```js
const users = [
  { id: 1, name: 'john' },
  { id: 2, name: 'john' },
  {
    id: 3, name: 'john',
    assignments: [
      { id: 1, userId: 3, postId: 2 }
    ]
  },

]

const assignments = [
  { id: 1, userId: 3, postId: 2 }
]


assignments.forEach(assignment => {

  const index = users.findIndex(
    user => user.assignments ? user.assignments.findIndex(a => a.id === assignment.id && a.userId === assignment.userId && a.postId === assignment.postId) : -1);
  if (index > -1) {
    users.splice(index, 1);
  }
});

console.log(users);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not it's working like the above codes apply for all `postId` such as the same duplicate deleting for other `postId`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code hope this will work for you.

```
users = [
    {id: 1, name: 'john'},
    {id: 2, name: 'john'},
    {id: 3, name: 'john',
        assignments: [
            {id: 1, userId: 3, postId: 2}
        ]
    },   
]
assignments = [
    {id: 1, userId: 3, postId: 2}
]
users.forEach(matchValueFunction);
function matchValueFunction(item,index) {   
    if(item.assignments){
        for(var i=0; i< assignments.length; i++){
            if(item.assignments[0].id == assignments[i].id && item.assignments[0].postId == assignments[i].postId){
                users.splice(index);
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(users);
```

Comment: This is not really different from the existing answers, it's just more complicated